# Is There A Way That Client Can Add Language Specific Inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I want to take language inputs from my clients. For example :

```html
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required="" id="en"> # For English Input
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required="" id="fr"> # For French Input
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required="" id="es"> # For Spanish Input
```

I want to store them as dictionary as the `{ 'lang' : 'title', 'lang2' : 'title2', 'lang3' : 'title3' }` pairs . I use Django as my backend. Is there a way that I can do that with Django forms?

Edit :
I tried this but it seems it doesn't working

```py
    def get_title(request):
        title = {}
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AddFoodCategoryForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                title = { 'fr' : form.cleaned_data.get('Français') }
                title = { 'en' : form.cleaned_data.get('English') }
                title = { 'ru' : form.cleaned_data.get('Pусский') }
                form['title'] = title
                form.save()
```

Comment: why do you use the same name for all inputs? Use different name (like `title_en`, `title_fr`, `title_sp`) for each input. Then you can get input you want with `form.cleaned_data['title_en']` (e.g.).

Comment: how can I save the data? if i want to make a three inputs i will end up creating three columns in database. i want them to be stored like { 'lang' : 'title', 'lang2' : 'title2', 'lang3' : 'title3' } in the database as well. (sorry for the trouble i'm pretty new to django)

Comment: if you're using postgres database [json field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) can be used to store data in the format you want.

Comment: i understand that but my question is how can i add more inputs on html without making new columns ?

Comment: please refer to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) for working with forms. As and example, you can write `lang_en=forms.CharField(max_length=2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to forms.py :

```py
def clean(self):
    if self.is_valid():
       title = { "fr" : self.cleaned_data.get("Français"),
                 "en" : self.cleaned_data.get("English"),
                 "ru" : self.cleaned_data.get("Pусский") }
       self.cleaned_data['title'] = title
```

And it worked.